# Can There be a Table in a Relational Database that Doesn't Have a Relationship to Any Other Table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have an application in which I store `PostId` and keywords (`Keyword`) belonging to a Post in a table named `KeywordsForPost`. The primary key for that table is the combination of `PostId` and `Keyword`. `PostId` is not unique nor is `Keyword`.

I needed this implementation because I might need to search for posts regarding the keywords they contain.

I have another table named `NewKeywords`. The one and only column in that table is `Keyword`. When a post is created, keywords in that post are inserted into both `KeywordsForPost` and `NewKeywords` tables. An operation is applied to the keywords in the table `NewKeywords` at the user's command so that they no longer become "New keywords". So I delete those keywords after that operation is applied. Currently my `NewKeywords` table does not have a relationship with any other table. Is this practice justified? Or is there a better practice?

I searched and found this answer.
[can we have a table without any relation with the other tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066015/in-a-relational-database-can-we-have-a-table-without-any-relation-with-the-othe)
But did not find it satisfactory.
I also find it different to the question previously asked because it asks a general question, whereas mine is specific. I need to know if a relationship can be added to the table. So far I came up with nothing.

Comment: What did you find unsatisfactory about that answer?

Comment: As all the answers indicate in the question you provided - yes, this is perfectly fine to do.  Just because you're working in a relational database does not mean that *all* tables *must* be related to at least one other.

Comment: For what it is worth the "Relational" in "Relational Database" does not actually refer to the relationships between tables (foreign keys), it refers to the related data with a single row within a table. For example a customer table might have forename, surname, date of birth and address. These separate items are related because they refer to the same customer.

Comment: Why not having a Keyword table with a flag of "New", and using the key of that table as foreign key of KeywordsForPost?

Comment: @TZHX Because it says a relationship can be added later if I wanted. I wanted to know if a good relationship existed in my case.

Comment: in case you want to do this by the books you can check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization it can be a bit fuzzy but these guidelines can help to a certain degree. However personally, after the 4th it gets overly complicated so i usually stop there unless necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  The only thing that could happen is that those table wouldn't have a relationship to other table.  i would not say that this is the best way to go, because all depend in your situation.  And, like the answer says: *It can still be given a relationship later.*

Comment: That's what I am interested about. If it can be given relationships later, what are they? I have done some head scratching and came up with nothing.

Comment: Hi @LilyLakshi , the first thing is try to understand database relationship review this site and let me know if you have more questions i will be waiting here =) http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Comment: @LilyLakshi take a look to this correct answer that work with the `ALTER TABLE` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308339/create-a-one-to-many-relationship-using-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Either I'm misreading your question, or there actually is a relationship between NewKeyWords and KeyWordsForPost.  It's a value (Keyword) that's common to both tables, and could be used for a relational join. That might be a stupid join that no one would want to do, it might be real slow, for lack of a relevant index, and the keywords aren't a declared key anywhere, but it's still a relationship.

The relationship is inherent in the data, whether you have declared it or not.

Comment: Yes. I understand a join can be made. I was interested to see if there can be a relationship that would enforce referential integrity of some sort. For an example `NewKeywords` should not have a value that is not present in `KeywordsForPost`. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Any two tables can be joined. You do not need a FK between them. The meaning of a JOIN is the AND of its arguments' meaning. A "relationship" in the sense of FK is just the *fact* that every referencing subrow appears as a referenced subrow. @LilyLakshi If that isn't true then there just isn't a FK. But "NewKeywords should not have a value that is not present in KeywordsForPost" (if you update the latter first). Hence "The relationship is inherent in the data, whether you have declared it or not."

Comment: Fair enough.  Any two tables can be joined with a cartesian join.  I meant an equijoin, but I didn't phrase it carefully.  My point about the existence of a relationship was in reference to a presumed ER model of the subject matter, and not in reference to a relational data model of the database design.  In the wording I'm accustomed to, an undeclared FK is still an FK.

Comment: @Lily, are you concerned about orphaned references?  If so, enforce RI.  If not, don't worry about it.

Comment: @WalterMitty Seeing that table on its own didn't feel right. Yes I wanted to enforce RI. But studying this for bit has made me convinced that it is not that big of a deal in this particular case. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @ WalterMitty Re ER: Yes it's clear that that was your context. I meant to put the "@LilyLakshi" a sentence earlier. RE Join: [Cartesian Join is just Join with restricted inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097), whether Natural Join or Equijoin (per the kind of relations/operators one is using). Eg SQL FROM always conceptually calculates a Cartesian Join. SQL just restricts syntax CROSS JOIN to have no ON and (INNER) JOIN to have an ON.

Comment: @philipxy. when you said "if you update the latter first" you might have added "or in the context of a single atomic transaction".  But I understand that you're trying to to throw in too much complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take [rlartiga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2662302/rlartiga)'s approach from a comment:

> Why not having a Keyword table with a flag of "New", and using the key of that table as foreign key of KeywordsForPost?

I am going to create a `Keywords` table with the column `Keyword` and have it as the primary key. Then I am going to have both `KeywordsForPost` and `NewKeywords` tables refer to `Keyword` in `Keywords`.